# How do I compile javascript together with typescript into one bundle?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, gulp, bundle

I'm working on a project where we have both js and ts files and they are supposed to be merged into one bundle file.

I'm using gulp-typescript and my configuration looks as follow:

```
           gulp.src(cfg.ts_src)
                   .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                   .pipe(typescript({
                       allowJs: true,
                       declaration: false,
                       diagnostics: false,
                       emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
                       experimentalDecorators: true,
                       module: "system",
                       moduleResolution: "classic",
                       noImplicitAny: true,
                       outFile: "./" + cfg.file,
                       preserveConstEnums: true,
                       pretty: true,
                       removeComments: true,
                       rootDir: "./static/" + cfg.dest,
                       target: "es5",
                   }))
               .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { sourceRoot: "/static/", includeContent: false }))
```

The problem I have is that when the configutation only contains js files, it creates a bundle with code. But when there is both js and ts file in the configuration, typescript ignores the javascript files and only compiles the ts files.

How can I create a bundle that contains code from both js and ts files and also still have working sourcemaps for the ts files?

Comment: Try first compiling all TS files and put them in temp dir, then bundle all those files with all your other js files.

Comment: Will I still have the typescript sourcemaps afterwards?

Comment: just copy them to your final dir with all the files

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Comment: Great, I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first compiling all TS files and put them in temp dir, then bundle all those files with all your other JS files.
Also copy all of your sourcemap files to the final dir.

Comment: Did that and it works, sometimes the simplest way of doing it is the best!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using old version of the gulp-typescript. Maybe this is an issue? Below is the task that works for me and emits both compiled ts + maps and any raw JS:

```
gulp.task('build.js.dev', () => 
{
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
        typescript: require('typescript')
    });

    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())   
        .pipe(tsProject());  

    return merge([
        //Write definitions 
        //tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest(TEMP_TARGET_FOLDER)),
        //Write compiled js
        tsResult.js.pipe(sourcemaps.write(
            ".", 
            { 
                includeContent: true, 
                sourceRoot: __dirname + "/dist"
            })).pipe(gulp.dest(TEMP_TARGET_FOLDER))]);
});
```

Note part: `tsResult.js.pipe(sourcemaps.write(`

You can refer to the gulp-typescript docs for more samples.

The tsconfig is pretty similar to your options:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": { 
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, 
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "module": "commonjs", 
     "target": "es6",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "outDir": "dist",
     "declaration": false,
     "allowJs": true,
     "jsx": "react",
     "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
     "types": [
        "node",
        "jasmine"
     ]
 },
 "exclude": [
     "./node_modules",
     "./dist",
     "./.vscode"
 ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using latest, but maybe an old way of configurating it.
I'm trying to compile it into one single file - yours doesn't as what I can see. But I've solved it now.